SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'contaBase.contadors' doesn't exist
Llevo un rato sacando cosas, y ya no se si es que simplemente no veo y me hace falta descansar, pues:  Table 'contaBase.contadors', "debería" ser el nombre de mi tabla, pero, no, y cuando busco esa cadena:"contadors", no encuentro nada......y solo puede estar en unos pocos archivos...(5 que son los que se modificaron para hacer lo que quería hacer)
Paso la parte que contiene donde podría estar el "fallo":
rutas:
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\JuegosController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PartidasController;
use App\Http\Controllers\JugadoresController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DadosController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContadoresController;
.
.
.
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  .
  .
  .
  Route::get('/Contadores', [ContadoresController::class, 'index'])->name('Contadores');
  Route::post('/Contadores/stor', [ContadoresController::class, 'store'])->name('storeContador');
  Route::post('/Contadores/destroy/{contador}', [ContadoresController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroyContador');
  Route::get('/Contadores/{contador}', [ContadoresController::class, 'view'])->name('viewContador');
}

config de adminlte (sección menú):
        ['header' => 'Utilidades'],
        [
            'text' => 'Dados',
            'icon_color' => 'purple',
            'url' => 'Dados',
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Contadores',
            'icon_color' => 'cyan',
            'url' => 'Contadores',
        ],

Modelo (que no creo que sea....):
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contador extends Model{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}

Controller que solo tiene una funcion programada( y es donde "dice" que esta el "fallo":
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Contador;

class ContadoresController extends Controller{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(){
        $contadores = Contador::all();
        return view ("contatore",['contadores'=>$contadores]);
    }

Lo otro si lo tengo que poner borro algo de lo que esta bien.

No se porque, no cogió el nombre correcto, si cambio el nombre de la tabla en la base de datos, no hay problema......

Da la impresión de que alguien se come una "e". ¿Habras puesto una "e" con algún diacrítico (acento, dieresis) que el sistema se come en alguna parte? Se me ocurre extraer todas las palabras de los fuentes, seleccionar todas las que contiene "contador", eliminar los duplicados y ver que queda. Idea loca.

La cosa es que cree la tabla a mano, sin artisan migrate, y el resto de archivos como el modelo y el controlador si así como la migración también, pero se me ocurrió hacer esa a mano y al darme ese error, me da la "opción" de migrar, pero, no lo hace, no se porque, toma como tabla por "defecto" esa (contadors), quizás porque no hice la migración.

Falta el error completo y las tablas de la base de datos. Hay una ruta que dice stor, cuando todo el resto es store. Y otra parte que dice contatore en vez de contadores

Esta hecho, simplemente, cambie el nombre en la base de datos que tenia, luego haré mas pruebas, la ruta esta corregida ya, la parte de "contatore" lo hice adrede, es el nombre del blade, vendría a ser lo mismo que el "index", para que no haya confusión, aunque me parece que la hay....

Esto que te pasa es el comportamiento por defecto de Eloquent, al definir el Model asume que el nombre de la tabla es el nombre del modelo en "plural"... es decir, simplemente le agrega una s (ja)
Si el modelo se llama Contador, entonces el plural debe ser... Contadors

[...] Por convención, el «caso de serpiente», el nombre plural de la clase se utilizará como el nombre de la tabla a menos que se especifique explícitamente otro nombre. Así, en este caso, Eloquent asumirá que el modelo Flight almacena los registros en la tabla flights.
Laravel > Eloquent: Getting Started > Table Names

Solución:
Al definir el modelo, podes indicar manualmente el nombre de la tabla:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contador extends Model{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = 'contadores';
}

